# Does the Uncharted 1&2 Twin Pack come with the bonuses of Uncharted 2 GOTY?

Tags: version-differences, uncharted, uncharted-2

Sony recently released an [Uncharted 1 & 2 Twin Pack](http://au.playstation.com/ps3/news/articles/detail/item376168/Twin-Pack-Offers/) (in Australia at least). I haven't played either before and was wondering if getting this bundle was worth it. [Uncharted 2 Game of the Year Edition](http://www.naughtydog.com/site/post/uncharted_2_game_of_the_year_edition/) comes with some perks that look good, but the Twin Pack seems like it contains the original version of #2 (from its cover art and list of features). This seems a bit odd to me considering the GOTY version came out a year or so previous.

Has anyone had experience with this Twin Pack? Or does someone know for sure what's included one way or another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in the US, my copy of Uncharted 2 in the twin pack is the GOTY edition, and came with a PSN voucher code for all the bonus content.  I can't be sure this is the case with an Australian copy, but it doubly doesn't make sense for there to be a GOTY edition they're not giving you AND for there to be a version difference this significant between the regions.

Comment: That's my thinking too; thanks for providing your experience. I'll get the twin pack then and leave an update for any curious Aussies.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you're near a store, I bet inspecting a physical copy might answer the question pre-purchase - my US copy listed it as GOTY edition pretty plainly even on the cardboard sleeve, if I remember correctly.